# Automatically running SQL Server 2016 Job

Tags: sql-server

We have several jobs in SQL Server 2012 that we run under the Windows Task Scheduler but they will not run under 2016.  Is there any way to run 2016 jobs automatically?

Comment: just run them in sql agent service, that is where its for

Comment: To expand on Guido's comment , take a peek at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent

Comment: This does not appear to be about programming; it seems that it should've been posted on DBA, not SO.

Comment: SQL Server jobs are run by SQL Server's Agent. The agent can perform a lot of database specific jobs, use query results in jobs etc. While you can use Windows Task Scheduler to run commands through eg `sqlcmd`, it's almost never used

Answer (score 1):

in SSMS open the object explorer and navigate to SQL Server Agent.
There you can add jobs and schedule them exact like you need

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is what I thought.  Unfortuantely our instalaltion of SQL Server 2106 does not include the agent.

Comment: Then I guess you need to address the root cause of your problem: why those tasks don't run in the Task Scheduler in the 2016 version.